# Equivalent in RxJava

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

We can execute some code asynchronously in C# Rx, as shown below, using `Observable.Start()`. I am wondering what is the equivalent in RxJava.

```
void Main()
{
      AddTwoNumbersAsync (5,4)
      .Subscribe(x=>Console.WriteLine(x));

}
IObservable<int> AddTwoNumbersAsync(int a, int b)
{
      return Observable.Start(() => AddTwoNumbers(a, b));
}
int AddTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: @DanielA.White I have gone through some blogs and they were using Executors or threads. I was thinking there should be a simple way and hence the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can defer the operation until subscription, and ensure that subscription happens on another thread:

```
Observable<Integer> sumDeferred = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call() {
            return Observable.just(addTwoNumbers(5, 4));
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
sumDeferred.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Is this the only way? On this netflix blig, I see them using Executors. Wondering whats the difference in that and this approach. http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/02/rxjava-netflix-api.html

Comment: I doubt this is the only way - using an Executor is simply handling the threading explicitly yourself. This answer is the only way I've found to avoid that, though I'd be eager to see a better solution.

Comment: `Start` has the exact opposite semantics as `Defer` when it comes to temperature. Internally, `Start` starts the operation immediately and uses an `AsyncSubject` to capture the result.

Comment: @DaveSexton do you know which operator to use in RxJava?

Comment: No, sorry. When I read your question I searched the RxJava docs briefly but I didn't find anything related; otherwise, I would've answered the question myself :)

Comment: As Dave says, I don't believe there's a built-in to do this quite in this way. We're using the deferral method above to implement async observables in a few places in our app where a "hot" async observable would be better suited. This works, though, so it's not high on my priorities to find a better way just yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @AdamS and Dave I found few async operators on the wiki here but i don't see them in the API, https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Async-Operators

Comment: Async Operators is in another project: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaAsyncUtil because async apis are not stable, RxJava moved them to RxJavaAsyncUtil when it released 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Flowable Object from rxJava.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Flowable.fromCallable(() -> addTwoNumbersAsync(5, 4))
            .subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
    
private static int addTwoNumbersAsync(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The method call and the System print will be in a rxJava Thread, and not in the main Thread. You can specify the threadpool on which the Flowable will operate, by adding `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` before the `.subscribe(...)`for example.

You can also make a method, which returns the Flowable, which is closer to your original example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    addTwoNumbersAsync(5,4)
            .subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
    
private static Flowable<Integer> addTwoNumbersAsync(int a, int b) {
    return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> a+b);
}
```